# Azure Unzip automation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to do the following in Azure however I should point out that on my local machine I have no visual studio, no admin rights, no IT support and no tools (except SSMS) but I have a VERY strong drive to complete this work if its possible.

I have created an Azure blob which receives a file each day (zipped) from a 3rd party. I am looking to do the following:

1)Unzip the data in an automated fashion

2)Get the data into an Azure SQL database (already created) in an automated fashion

What I want to know is if this is possible to do using Azure alone or am I going to need admin rights / Visual Studio? If it is possible any directions that you could point me in would be greatly received!

Thanks

Dave

Comment: since your pc is not involved in the process in any way, share, or form you dont need admin rights. you can use azure automation to create a powershell script to do this. I dont really have any examples, nor do I have the time to search\investigate this. hence this is a comment :)

Comment: What is the format of the files contained inside the ZIP file?

Comment: What is the size of your zip file ?

Comment: @Thomas - the files are about 100mb

Comment: @Alberto Morillo - We recieve either zip or gzip (option) inside the file they are TSV files.

Comment: @4c74356b41 - thanks - sounds promising

Comment: automation or azure function , how do you plan to import your data into sql ???

Comment: @Thomas - I am very new to all of this but the blob functions is where I am currently looking.

Comment: To get the better from blob storage, you should have a look at eventgrid blob event + azure function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, one approach would be to create a Blob Triggered Azure Function through the Azure Portal (Visual Studio is not required), unzip/process the file and save desired data into Azure SQL. Moreover, considering the there is only one new file per day, prefer the Consumption Plan to optimize cost.

Find more details about Azure Function Blob Binding at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's great to know that this is possible. I will look into Triggered Azure functions.

Comment: It's possible you do not have unzip the file to load it.  Azure Data Factory (ADF) Copy activity can deal with zipped files, although you will have to try with your particular file, I don't think it's all formats.  Configure the 'Compression type' of the Source dataset in the Copy activity.  Options are:  .bzip, .gzip, .deflate, .zip., tar, .snappy, .iz4.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, one approach would be to create a Blob Triggered Azure Function through the Azure Portal (Visual Studio is not required), unzip/process the file and save desired data into Azure SQL. Moreover, considering the there is only one new file per day, prefer the Consumption Plan to optimize cost.

Find more details about Azure Function Blob Binding at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.

Answer (score 0):

Spin up your data factory on Azure, unzip function is available on adf